# Modal solo cierra haciendo click afuera

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Necesito que mi popup modal cierre solo si le hago click en la imagen o bien en una x de "cerrar" en la imagen.
El codigo que tengo actualmente es:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 13%;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hooters.cr/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/PopUp-Reserve.png" alt="image" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
$( function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah pues en el inicio donde empieza el html de tu modal checa que contenga lo siguiente:

```
class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"
```

Un ejemplo:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" id="idDeTuModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitulo" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- ...demás codigo del bs-modal -->
</div>
```

Y con eso cierras mediante el botoncito "x" del modal únicamente.

Para lo de hacer clic para cerrar el modal con la imagen asígnale un id, por ejemplo:

```
<img id="imgcerrar_bs_modal" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hooters.cr/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/PopUp-Reserve.png" alt="image" />
```

Y en tu javascript (y ya que estás usando jquery) pones lo siguiente:

```
$('#imgcerrar_bs_modal').click(function() {
    $('#idDeTuModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Con agregar `data-dismiss="modal"` a la imagen tiene que ser suficiente, el código javascript no debería hacer falta.